# How to drop remove rows from tibble based on multiple column values( duplicate and string value)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I can't figure out how to do this. In the tibble below I would like to drop row 4 based on few things.

1. models == "EADS142"
2. duplicate attribute BC02S present in row 3 which models =="EADS14"
   I don't want to drop row 2 although models=="EADS142" and duplicate attributes in row 1 because in row 1 models !="EADS14"

``

```
 filtered
# A tibble: 7 x 2
attributes models 
<chr>        <chr>   
1 AGG413.    EADS05
2 AGG413     EADS142
3 BC02S      EADS14
4 BC02S      EADS142

Expected result
# A tibble: 4 x 2
attributes models 
<chr>      <chr>  
1 AGG413     EADS05 
2 AGG413     EADS142 
3 BC02S      EADS14
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `duplicated` with `lag` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(!(duplicated(attributes) & 
           models == 'EADS142' & lag(models) == 'EADS14'))

#  attributes  models
#1    AGG413.  EADS05
#2     AGG413 EADS142
#3      BC02S  EADS14
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(attributes = c("AGG413.", "AGG413", "BC02S", "BC02S"
), models = c("EADS05", "EADS142", "EADS14", "EADS142")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```